# Java/Tomcat heap size question

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, windows-server-2008, ram

I am not a Java dev, but an app landed on my desk.  It's a web-service server-side app that runs in a Tomcat container.  The users hit it up from a client application.

The users constantly complain about how slow it is and the app has to be restarted about twice a week, cause things get really bad.

The previous developer told me that the app simply runs out of memory (as it loads more data over time) and eventually spends all its time doing garbage collection.  Meanwhile, the Heap Size for Tomcat is set at 6GB.  The box itself has 32GB of RAM.

Is there any harm in increasing the Heap Size to 16GB?
Seems like an easy way to fix the issue, but I am no Java expert.

Comment: Maybe you should figure out what is the total size you of data you want to "permanently" cache. Otherwise it looks like you need a better caching solution (Ehcache).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no harm in increasing the Heap Size to 16GB.

Answer (score 5):

You should identify the leak and fix it, not add more heap space.  Thats just a stop gap.

You should configure tomcat to dump the heap on error, then analyze the heap in one of any number of tools after a crash.  You can compute the retained sizes of all the clases, which should give you a very clear picture of what is wrong.

Im my profile I have a link to a blog post about this, since I had to do it recently.

Comment: @hvgotcodes There is no memory leaks.  Over time the app must load gigantic data sets into memory.  Eventually it loads enough of these data sets that it runs out of memory.  The reason, it does not unload the data set after being done with it is that another user might want the same info.  And loading the dataset into RAM is the most time consuming step.

Comment: @angryhacker, then its done incorrectly.  You have an app that will always crash after some amount of time, under normal operation.  You should be caching a reasonable amount of data, not all data for all time.

Comment: @angryhacker, one thing you can do is just write some sort of OS level process to restart the app server every n days when you have light usage.  but thats not a fix, its just something to make it look better to users...

Comment: A helpful tool to analyse the behavior may be VisualVM http://java.net/projects/visualvm/content/ which is also included in current Java SE installations IIRC.

Comment: @hvgotcodes, If there is 32GB of RAM on the machine and all the data can fit into 10GB, why not cache all data all the time?  I could understand if I was on a memory constrained machine, but I am not.  So back to my original question, is there any harm in increasing the Heap Size to 16GB?

Comment: @angryhacker, you didnt mention that all data is 10gb in your original question.  You can certainly try it.  Are you using 64 bit java?  32bits cant access 10gb of memory.

Comment: @hvgotcodes, 32bit Java can't access 6GB either :).  Yes, it's 64-bit Java and the data is being added at a rate of about 500mb per year, so I figure 16GB should last for a while.

Comment: @hvtgotcodes: *"You should identify the leak and fix it, not add more heap space."*...  In the Real-World [TM] sometimes you don't have that luxury: multi-billion $$$ company here, we're depending, in PROD, on a Tomcat webservice that keeps failing.  The service responsible is overloaded with requests and they simply don't have the time/manpower to fix it.  Result?  A non-stop shell script monitoring the JVM's status and restarting Tomcat when things become messy.  Sure, it sucks.  Welcome to the Real-World [TM].

Comment: @hvtgotcodes: Funnily enough, because the app is "well-designed" (it can't leave the DB in a corrupt state) and because on a Un*x box *kill -9* is **guaranteed** to free all the resources used by a process, that crappy shell script actually works very well and saved our asses.

Comment: @syntaxt3rr0r a few things: 1) the original question was incomplete, and OP indicates he's sure its not a mem leak, its just the way it is designed 2) OP indicates that the total data in the system is less than the memory on the server, and all that was addressed in comments, 3) in the real world, its acceptable to do stop-gap measures to keep things going until a better solution can be found (see the third comment in the chain), if the decision is made to even find one.  In the real world, there are those who fix these types of issues, and those that don't want to/can't...

Comment: @syntaxt3rr0r, you don't need to lead all the data into the app to have data safety -- in fact if the app updates the db at all, and does it incorrectly, then i bet it is possible to corrupt the data.  I agree that  monitoring/restarting is ok to relieve bad user experience until a better solution is found.

Answer (score 1):

> The previous developer told me that the app simply runs out of memory (as it loads more data over time)

This looks like a *memory leak*, a serious bug in application. If you increase the amount of memory available from 6 to 16 GiB, you're still gonna have to restart the application, only less frequent. Some experienced developer should take a look at the application heap while running (look at *hvgotcodes* tips) and fix the application.

Comment: I assure you the app will not run out of memory given that it has enough of it to load all the data.  There is no memory leak. I've removed most of the data and tried it on my machine, and it worked fine.  However, it's one thing to try it locally, quite a different thing with 1000s of users hitting it.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve these issues you need to do performance testing.  This includes both CPU and memory analysis.  The JDK (6) bundles a tool called VisualVM, on my Mac OS X machine this is on the path by default as "jvisualvm".  That's free and bundled, so it's a place to start.

Next up is the NetBeans Profiler (netbeans.org).  That does more memory and CPU analysis.  It's free as well, but a bit more complicated.

If you can spend the money, I highly recommend YourKit (http://www.yourkit.com/).  It's not terribly expensive but it has a lot of built-in diagnostics that make it easier to figure out what's going on.

The one thing you can't do is assume that just adding more memory will fix the problem.  If it's a leak, adding more memory may just make it run really badly a bit longer between restarts.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a profiling tool like JProfiler, VisualVM, jConsole, YourKit etc.  You can take a heap dump of your application and analyze which objects are eating up memory.